# Running gtest with a command line gives errors

Tags: c++, testing, c++17, googletest

I want to run a unit test of a C++ class with gtest from with a command line under Ubuntu x64. I was following a tutorial from a book, which used the following command to to this:

```
g++ -o tester.exe MyClass1.cpp MyClass1Test.cpp 
-I googletest/googletest -I googletest/googletest/include
-I googletest/googlemock -I googletest/googlemock/include 
-I usr/lib/libgtest.a -l -lpthread
```

Original command suggested by "Mastering C++ Programming" (Jeganathan Swaminathan):

```
g++ -o tester.exe src/Math.cpp test/MathTest.cpp 
-I googletest/googletest -I googletest/googletest/include 
-I googletest/googlemock -I googletest/googlemock/include 
-I src libgtest.a -lpthread
```

My 3 files look like this:

**"MyClass1.cpp"**

```
#include "MyClass1.h"

bool MyClass1::checkEquality(int number1, int number2) {

        int result = number1 - number2;

        if(result == 0) {
                return true;
        }
        else {
                return false;
        }

}

int main() {}
```

**"MyClass1.h"**

```
class MyClass1 {
public:
    bool checkEquality(int number1, int number2);
};
```

**"MyClass1Test.cpp"**

```
#include "MyClass1.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST ( MyClass1Test, checkIntEquality) {

        MyClass1 myClass;

        bool expectedResult = true;
        int number1 = 10;
        int number2 = 10;

        bool result = myClass.checkEquality(number1, number2);

        EXPECT_EQ(expectedResult, result);
}
```

I already tried playing around with the order of the parameters as suggested when I searched for an solution, but this did not give me a different output. I also read that the lpthread library has something to do with this issue but I am unsure what to do about this.

The output I get from the command above is:

```
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test::TestBody()':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `testing::Message::Message()'
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type, char const*, int, char const*)'
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text+0xb2): undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&) const'
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text+0xe7): undefined reference to `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text+0x17b): undefined reference to `testing::internal::GetTestTypeId()'
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*, char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test::MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test()':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text._ZN34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_TestC2Ev[_ZN34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_TestC5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `testing::Test::Test()'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `testing::internal::scoped_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::reset(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal10scoped_ptrINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE5resetEPS7_[_ZN7testing8internal10scoped_ptrINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE5resetEPS7_]+0x24): undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `testing::internal::scoped_ptr<std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::reset(std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal10scoped_ptrINSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE5resetEPS7_[_ZN7testing8internal10scoped_ptrINSt7__cxx1118basic_stringstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE5resetEPS7_]+0x23): undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<bool, bool>(char const*, char const*, bool const&, bool const&)':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal11CmpHelperEQIbbEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_[_ZN7testing8internal11CmpHelperEQIbbEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_]+0x36): undefined reference to `testing::AssertionSuccess()'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<bool, bool>(char const*, char const*, bool const&, bool const&)':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text._ZN7testing8internal18CmpHelperEQFailureIbbEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_[_ZN7testing8internal18CmpHelperEQFailureIbbEENS_15AssertionResultEPKcS4_RKT_RKT0_]+0x6c): undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o:(.rodata._ZTV34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test[_ZTV34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test]+0x20): undefined reference to `testing::Test::SetUp()'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o:(.rodata._ZTV34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test[_ZTV34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test]+0x28): undefined reference to `testing::Test::TearDown()'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o: In function `MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test::~MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test()':
MyClass1Test.cpp:(.text._ZN34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_TestD2Ev[_ZN34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_TestD5Ev]+0x20): undefined reference to `testing::Test::~Test()'
/tmp/ccJVQJv2.o:(.rodata._ZTI34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test[_ZTI34MyClass1Test_checkIntEquality_Test]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for testing::Test'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: please check that the command actually has `-I usr/lib/libgtest.a` ...

Comment: Actually the command only wanted ``libgtest.a`` but with this, it said that it cannot find libgtest so I put the full path there

Comment: The problem is that the `-I` switch is for an include

Comment: I added the original command from the tutorial in my question

Comment: I think the issue is that capital i and lowercase L look similar. Check that you have the right flags.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strange tutorial book. .exe extension is ridiculous for Linux, remove it.

```
g++ -o tester MyClass1.cpp MyClass1Test.cpp -Igoogletest/googletest -Igoogletest/googletest/include -Igoogletest/googlemock -Ioogletest/googlemock/include -lgtest -lpthread
```

Or

```
g++ -o tester MyClass1.cpp MyClass1Test.cpp -Igoogletest/googletest -Igoogletest/googletest/include -Igoogletest/googlemock -Ioogletest/googlemock/include /usr/lib/libgtest.a -lpthread
```

For Windows you could tune a development environment for Visual Studio with help of the tutorial [How to use Google Test for C++ in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-use-google-test-for-cpp)?

Comment: The first command actually does not produce any output at all, the second one says ``g++: error: usr/lib/libgtest.a: No such file or directory`` even tho it exists?

Comment: Where is it existing, the full path and the working directory please? Try to use this full path. The path in my answer is based on your question. Thus you are responsible for the correct path.

Comment: The path should be `/usr/lib/...` not `usr/lib/...` (note the starting `/`)

Comment: You are right, however, the command still does not give me any output

Comment: I got the command to create my output file. However, now the problem is that I cannot run it. ./tester.exe gives me no output.

Comment: Nothing. No output

Comment: I just followed the tutorial and for some reason they are doing it with the ``.exe`` file on MacOS. I already tried various different files, I can not get any of them to be executed as expected